# How to edit homepage in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html

I'm gonna add a bit of code/edit my homepage in Wordpress, but I can't find the page's main file to edit. Take a look at this:

http://uaral.com

This is my homepage. Now look at the page source in your browser. I want to edit these codes. But I can't find it anywhere in the website directory. It seems to be a html file, but can't find anything on the host to edit. I'm a total newbie, so please explain it clear. I'm using WordPress 3.6.1 and Wallbase theme. Thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend to read some introductions to WordPress: for starters, [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). As for now, this is not enough information to get actual help. The final HTML of your website is generated both by static and dynamic parts. Is it some specific page that you want to customize? Is it a somewhat general part of the website (like the header, footer, sidebar etc.)?

Comment: I'm a newbie and I know nothing about php. I wonder why the source of the page is in html, but all the files are in php.

Comment: Yes, it's the main page (uaral.tk), and I want to edit the header of it.

Comment: PHP files are often used to produce markup that is sent to browsers. Using only pure HTML files to produce web pages is very rare when using WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it really is the header you want to edit, you can find its source here:

> /wp-content/themes/Wallbase/header.php

Depending on A) what it is exactly that you want to customize, and B) how your theme is set up and what options it comes with, you might want to try the [Theme Options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Theme_Options_Screen), which can be found in the *Appearance* menu in WordPress Admin, **if** present (the options, that is).

If it is some CSS thing, however, you have to edit the theme's stylesheet:

> /wp-content/themes/Wallbase/style.css

Comment: I want to add an Ajax Search Bar to the top of the home page.

Comment: @MohammadRezaHajianpour then head on to http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=ajax+search&sort=